# How to create an index for a complex MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, indexing

I need to create an index for the following query:

```
await Activity.find({
   $and: [
      {
         lastUpdated: {
            $gte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
         },
      },
      {
         "followers._user": _user,
      },
      {
         global: true,
      }
   ]
})
.collation({
   locale: "en_US",
   numericOrdering: true,
})
.sort({
   lastUpdated: -1
})
.skip(
   length
)
.limit(
   10
)
```

I have the below index in place currently but the query does not use it.

```
ActivitiesSchema.index(
  { "followers._user": 1, global: 1, lastUpdated: -1 },
  {
    collation: {
      locale: "en_US",
      numericOrdering: true,
    },
  }
);
```

What can I try to solve this?

Comment: How do you know if it is used or not?  Normally I would execute the query in MongoShell using an explain() to see how the planner expects to execute the query.  Have you verified the index has been created?  Generally speaking, having your application create indexes is a bad practice as creating the index may place stress on a busy system.  Rather than have the application create the index it is recommended the index is created on off-peak hours.  When using MMS (Atlas, Ops Manager) you can apply an index in a rolling fashion with little impact to a production system.

Comment: @barrypicker I second every word regarding index management on application level but Mongoose community have slightly different opinion on that point https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes. They do recommend to disable automatic index update on production systems, so it wouldn't be fair to label it a "bad practice" and confuse people who just started to learn this quite opionated ODM.

Comment: @barrypicker Atlas shows me that it hasn't been used for X days that is how I know. For some reason I cannot get explain() to work for me but I do see an explanation in the Profile tab in Atlas which shows me that over 2k records (all of them) are being scanned and returned. I hear you with the creation of indexes but this is a single business application located in one area and has very little impact on production system as I do updates in off hours.

Comment: You don't need an index if your whole collection contains only 2k documents.

Comment: @AlexBlex I know that for production. Those are numbers from my development database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change index to:

```
{ lastUpdated: -1, "followers._user": 1, global: 1 }
```

**NB:** it may affect other queries that rely on existing index

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-index-prefix reads:

> If the sort keys correspond to the index keys or an index prefix, MongoDB can use the index to sort the query results. A prefix of a compound index is a subset that consists of one or more keys **at the start** of the index key pattern.

Since you are sorting by "lastUpdated", the index should start from it.

**NB 2:** With this change Mongodb **can** use, but it is not guaranteed. There are many other factors like selectivity and cardinality, e.g. `global: true,` implies extremely low cardinality to benefit from an index on this field. On the other hand if the user doesn't follow much and the total activity is massive, it might be cheaper to filter by "followers._user" index and do in-memory sort. It's up to the query planner to decide which index to use.

Comment: This did it! Thank you!